# SQL Query - multiple search terms, two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm wondering if someone could provide some guidance on an SQL query to return results from two columns using a varying amount terms. It's SQLite3 in Node.js. This is a music library search function, so I want to be able to type something like "Justin Peaches" or "Bieber Peaches" or "Justin Bieber Peach" which would return the same result. Currently, my SQL query is:

`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE track LIKE '' or artist LIKE '' ORDER BY track LIMIT 12;`

**table:** "songs"

**track:** Peaches (Clean) **artist:** Justin Bieber (featuring Daniel Caesar)

Obviously this only allows searching of artist OR song rather than both at the same time. I would like to be able to enter individual words of the artist, song, or a combination of both. It's very similar to the way you'd search pretty much any other music library wherein you can use a combination of artist, track, or some of each.

I'm not sure if this is something that can be accomplished directly in an SQL query or if there needs to be some additional handling in advance. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the database? I removed the inconsistent tags, so you can specify a single one.

Comment: can you please create an example of what kind of columns you have along with sample values and what do you need as the desired output. It is not so clear

Comment: It's SQLite3, Node.js. I've added a few sample values, hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: You should take a look at [Full Text Searches](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html)